# Struct inheritance in factory pattern

Tags: go, inheritance, factory

I need to create inheritor for some struct:

```
// Not interface, pure struct
type Base struct {
  A int
  B string
}

type Child struct {
  Base
  C bool
}

func (c *Child) SomeLoop() {
  for {
    // business logic
  }
}
```

create Child instance and return from factory

```
func maker() *Base {
  child := &Child {
    Base {
      A: 1
      B: "2"
    },
    C: false,
  }
  go child.Some()
  return child
}
```

Objects which making from factory using as Base struct with fields A and B

```
o := maker()
fmt.Println(o.A, o.B)
```

But I cannot return `child` as `base` from `maker` func. How to realize this pattern?

Comment: There is no inheritance in Go. At all.

Comment: You cannot return a `*Child` as a `*Base` because they are different types.  That much should be clear. What is the actual goal you are trying to achieve? There's probably a better way.

Comment: It seems like you are applying terms form other language ecosystem to Go. Go is a distinct language on its own. So rather than that, please tell us what kind of behaviour do you want to achieve - there would be a Go way to do it.

Comment: I want to create objects from from few fabrics and store in slice
<code>
  objects := []Base{
    makeChild1(), // fabric of Child1
    makeCHilds2(), // fabric of Child2
    makeChild3(), // fabric of Child3 
  }
  for _, o := range objects {
    fmt.Println(o.A, o.B)
  }
</code>
Base struct are external. I am cannot modify Base struct from external package.

Comment: When you say fabric, I'm pretty sure you mean [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)), am I right?

Comment: yes) 
Sorry, language singularity

Comment: So if you want different types of objects to fit in a slice together, you would normally use an interface. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: Yes, now I'm using interface as return type from `maker` func. But  this need to create too much code. For each `maker` func

Comment: I don't tink I follow. If you have a single `Base` and lots of `Child`-style types, each of which embeds `Base`, then either have construction func for each "child" type accept a `Base` or, if you want to initialize embedded `Base` in each "child" type using child-special logic, then make `Base` implement `Initialize(...)` and call it with relevant parameters when constructing each "child" type. And I failed to get "too much code for each `maker func" passage since if you need to have different initializers for differet "child" types you _bound_ to write diferend code for each—by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Golang does not have inheritance, only embedding. You cannot return `child` as `*Base` from `maker()`. However, you can return `&child.Base` (losing the link to `child` in the returned value in the process).

The closest you can get to what you want is to define an `interface{}` for `Base` with the "ability" (functions) to return the values of `A` and `B`:

```golang
type BaseInterface interface { // Don't actually name it like this
    // You would usually omit the "Get", but then
    // we'd get a name conflict with the fields later.
    // This may be avoided by making them lowercase, i.e. private.
    GetA() int
    GetB() string
}
```

Then, you can implement this for `*Child`:

```golang
// Note how this implements BaseInterface for Child and *Child alike.

func (child *Child) GetA() int {
    return child.A
}

func (child *Child) GetB() string {
    return child.B
}
```

Then, you could return it as `BaseInterface` and, if needed, later do a type assertion to get the original type of `*Child`:

```golang
returnedValue.(*Child) // Yes, this really is what the syntax looks like.
```

This is sometimes necessary, and has been admitted by Rob Pike (one of Golang's inceptors) to be one of the aspects of the language they are not proud of during [a talk at dotGo 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9Zbuuo51go). The takeaway is to not try to introduce complications in your code which the language is designed to avoid.